# ad7689 output code differes with vref

Tags: adc

so I configured the adc(ad7689) using lpc1768,and here is what i get:(a few conversions of each for the same voltage)

- VDD=5v,vref=4.096v
- 4bcf>> v=1.2129
- 4bdf>> v=1.2139
- 4b8f>> v=1.2089

but

- VDD=5v,vref=2.5v
- 8007>>1.2502
- 8004>>1.2501
- 800f>>1.2505

i cant find where the source of this issue is,any help is appreciated.

Comment: What issue?  What do you expect?

Comment: Maybe because $$N_{counts}=\frac{V_{ref}}{V{x}}(2^{N_{ADC}}-1)$$

Comment: is N the code? and vx the input analog?

Comment: my question is, why would i get different outputs from different reference voltages?

Answer (score 1):

As described in my comment, sorry for the typo : 
$$N_{counts}=\frac{V_{x}}{V_{ref}}(2^{N_{adc}}-1)$$
where $$N_{counts}$$ means result from ADC, $$V_{x}$$ is measured voltage and $$N_{adc}$$ are ADC bits resolution (12-bit, 10-bit,etc). The adc compares unknown voltage with reference voltage and encodes the number rapresenting the voltage, therefore it is normal if you change V_ref to get different result.
For example your ADC is 16-bit therefore 2^N-1=65535:
$$\frac{1.2129}{4.096}*65535 = 19406.1 ,rounding=19406= 4BCE_{HEX} $$

Comment: So how should i know which vref is giving me the exact voltage value?